# Executing Javascript in a frameset

Tags: javascript, frames

```
<frameset name="main">
 <frame src="leftnav.php" name="leftframe"/>
 <frame  src="dashboard.php" name="rightframe" bgcolor="#000000"/>
</frameset>
```

Hey. I want to execute some JavaScript in the rightframe and that should then affect in the left frame.

I guess the question is... what do I need to prefix my javascript with so it is accessible in the left frame?

Comment: frames are BAD ! We're not in the 90's anymore

Comment: But sometime we need to fix or modify old stuffs without rewrite the page.

Comment: Precisely. Sometimes it is cheaper to not replace the templating system on a 2000 file PHP app...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in a page wich is in the right frame and you want to access an element in a page in the left frame you can use for example:

```
var table=parent.leftframe.document.getElementById("information");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can: `parent.leftframe.var_name` and `parent.leftframe.function_name()`

Answer (score 1):

In a comment to the original question (above), @Valentin mentions that frames are "bad," but does not explain further.  Here are some references that do:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/144515/290869

[Frames deprecated in HTML5 but not iFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10159741/5025060)

[Why are frames deprecated in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4263509/5025060)

Answer (score 0):

index.html:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hello () {
        alert('Say hello!');
    }
</script>
<frameset name="main">
 <frame src="frame1.html" name="leftframe"/>
</frameset>
...
```

frame1.html

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    parent.hello(); // OR parent.YOU_FRAME_NAME
</script>
...
```