# setting <object>'s data attribute with javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I am trying to display a webpage inside a div on click of a link to that webpage.

On click of the link, I prevent the browser from going to the link, show the div, and give the `<object>` inside the div the url of the link that was clicked.

This all works fine, the div shows, and the object gets the url of the clicked link as the value of its data attribute.

My problem is that the `<object>` is not displaying anything. According to dev tools it is there, but I don't see the webpage.

Here is my javascript / jQuery code:

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
$('#tabViewWindow').show();
$('#tabViewWindow object').attr('data', $(this).attr('href'));
$('#tabVieWindow embed').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
});
```

and here is the full code of the file where the problem exists when I run it locally:

```
<!Doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Tab View</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body{
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    #tabViewWindow{
        height:100%;
        height:100vh;
        width:100%;
        width:100vw;
        position:absolute;
        background:#000000;
        display:none;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        z-index:10000000000000000;
    }
    embed, object, iframe, img{
        max-width:100%;
        margin:0 auto;
        display:block;
    }
    object{
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tabViewWindow">
            <object data="">
                <embed src="" />
            </object>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="http://wolfram.com">Wolfram.com</a>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="http://wikipedia.org">Wikipedia.org</a>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="http://google.com">Google.com</a>
        <br />
        <br />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('a').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#tabViewWindow').show();
            $('#tabViewWindow object').attr('data', $(this).attr('href'));
            $('#tabVieWindow embed').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: youre misusing $(this)

Comment: why not use an iframe?

Comment: @ScottSelby - Explain, `$(this)` in that context is `<a>`. http://jsfiddle.net/cCs3n/

Comment: @ScottSelby How. `$(this)` refers to the anchor in this case.

Comment: @MisterMelancholy I thought iFrames were deprecated in HTML 5

Comment: _<frame>_ is depricated. _<iframe />_ is not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159741/frames-deprecated-in-html5-but-not-iframes

Comment: @MisterMelancholy Ah, that must be what I am confusing it with. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an iFrame, it works (at least on FF and Chrome, latest) - see: http://jsfiddle.net/WSW9J/1/

```
<div id="tabViewWindow">
    <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

Is there a reason why you want to use an object tag instead ?

By the way, if you just want to display a snippet of another website in your page, you may be interested in http://pagepeeker.com/

Comment: I chose an object tag because I though `<iframe>` was deprecated in HTML5. In other words, no longer supposed to be used or supported.

Comment: I can't sue pagepeeker because they have to be live not screenshots.

Comment: Iframes are not depricated in HTML5, but the original frame tag is.