# Using framesets with Google appengine

Tags: html, google-app-engine, python-2.7, frameset

I was wondering if anyone could show me an example for using html framesets with google appengine for python 2.7. What i want to do is have two frames, one static frame containing a sidebar with buttons and then another frame to the right of it that shows different pages depending on which button is selected.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you really need to use frames? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263509/why-are-frames-deprecated-in-html  Without much knowledge of Python, I am almost certain there is a way to do this using server-side templates.

Comment: There is nothing special you need to do on app engine as any other platform. It's mostly just html to achieve what you want

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented, this is something that can be solved client-side and you shouldn't be using frames.

Zurb foundation offers navigation similar to what you are requesting.
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/navigation.php

Similarly, Twitter bootstrap also offers navigation that would enable you to build the functionality you are requesting.
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

A plugin that will help you keep a sticky side menu can be found here: http://mojotech.github.com/stickymojo/

In response to your comment:
To dynamically load content into the 'frame' alongside the menu bar, you can use jQuery load function.
http://api.jquery.com/load/
It allows you to fetch a page from the server and replace an elements content with the fetched content.

Comment: yeah the navigation on zurb foundation was similar. But what i was really hoping for was a way to reload the main content without having to reload the sidebar.

Comment: @jrl589, I've responded to your comment in the answer.