# Jquery IE Issue, DOM is updated but page is not

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, dom

I am working in javascript/jquery and my code works in Chrome and FF.  I need it to work in IE and it does not.  There is no error explicit in output, but what i am doing has no effect.  All alerts suggest that everything is working correctly. I am working with a frameset like so:

```
<frameset rows="25%,75%">
    <frame name="frame1" src="ex.asp">
    <frameset cols="40%,60%">
        <frame name="frame2" src="wai.asp">
        <frame name="frame3" src="zee.asp">
    </frameset>
</frameset>
```

I am using JS functions to populate a table in frame 1.  This happens when something is selected in frame 2 or frame 3.  Once data is selected, Jquery is used to add a row to the table.

```
var test = window.top;
var body = $(test.frames[0].document.body);
$(body).find('#TxList').append('<tr>').text(sPayload);
```

there is also some forms that are populated like so:

```
window.top.frames[0].document.FORM.SELECTEDTX.value = sPayload;
```

etc.

So, this works in Chrome and FF but not in IE.  I used to DebugBar and looked at the page's DOM and my jquery data appears there as if there is no problem.  However it does not show up on the page and does not appear in "view source."

All of my scripts are on an external .js file.  What is happening?

Comment: try with closing tag too `.append('<tr></tr>')`

Comment: just a little friendly advice - do not use frames, they are [already deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4263583/467164) (and create more problems than they usually solve)

Comment: thanks! the closing tags worked. 

Zathrus, any suggestions on another route than frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `TD` to add text in `TR` and make sure `#TxList` is `table`

Try with -

```
$('#TxList').append('<tr><td>'+sPayload+'</td></tr>');
```