# How to Apply onmouseover to an Entire Frame?

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover

I have a frame that I want to run the equivalent of an onmouseover event whenever (surprise, surprise) someone mouses over the frame. I know I cannot use onmouseover with the frame or frameset tags. What could I do that would have the same effect as `<frame onmouseover=""...`?

Comment: Or you can wrap the `iframe` inside a `div` and apply `mouseover` on the div.

Answer (score 0):

`<frame>` s are [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263509/why-are-frames-deprecated-in-html) in modern versions of html.
You can just do something like:

```
<div onmouseover="javascript:alert('Hello!');" >
<iframe ...></iframe>
</div>
```