# Load an HTML file using javascript when NOT running on a server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, offline

I have two HTML files that are generated from a particular application; one is a navigation "header" file and the other is a "content" file that the navigation file points to.

I have access to these files but I don't have control over how they're generated.

The files currently fit together by a third file "index.html". The index file uses `document.write()` to create a `frameset` tag and then two `frame` tags, one for each HTML file noted above.

I'm writing a replacement index.html file that mimic's the frameset with `section` tags and then adds in some features that allows the user to perform processes on the "content" html file.

So far I'm able to accomplish this by using the jquery `load()` method to grab the navigation and content files, but when I take the files offline (these files are meant to be consumable directly from the desktop) it does not work. I read into the jquery documentation for `load()` and see that it needs to be run from a server.

My questions is: is there any way to load the content from one html file into another html file without being in a hosted environment? I've seen it work in other solutions like the [bwip-js](https://code.google.com/p/bwip-js/) and it looks like it's just using the jquery `load()`, but there must be something I'm missing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: is there a specific reason why you are using frameset as opposed to divs? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263509/why-are-frames-deprecated-in-html

Comment: It's the way the application that generates the files structures them. In my solution I'm replacing the index.html file that is generated (that uses the frameset) with `<section>` tags and trying to populate those tags with the contents of the two html files to get around using the frameset.

Comment: Can you post your code?