# Html Form Action and HTML Frame issue

Tags: css, html, forms, asp-classic

I have three classic asp files. Lets say 1.asp , 2.asp and 3.asp

In 1.asp , I have html form like below

```
<form action="2.asp" method="post">
```

So submitting the form goes to 2.asp as per the above code where I access the form request attributes in 2.asp

Now , I want 3.asp as a  frame  with 2.asp data as well.Basically Whenever a user clicks 1.asp form 
I want a page divided into two equal parts (i.e frames) with 2.asp and 3.asp

So I edited 1.asp file as

```
 <form action="customize.asp" method="post">
```

In customize.asp , I wrote Html frames like

```
<frameset cols="50%,50%">
  <frame src="2.asp">
  <frame src="3.asp">
</frameset>
```

Now , The real problem here is  whenever a user submits 1.asp form , the I am getting a page with two frames. 2.asp and 3.asp . Here 3.asp is looking fine. But 2.asp is not able to take  the html form attributes. **How to submit a form to one of the multiple  frames  in some html file?**

Comment: Why are you using frames?, consider [this answer to Why are frames deprecated in html?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4263583/692942). You can't submit to multiple `<frame>` or `<iframe>` without using some client-side code to initiate multiple submissions.

Comment: If you must use frames probably the easiest way to do this would be for customise.asp to collect the values from your form then pass them in a querystring, eg `<frame src="2.asp?arg1=value1&arg2=value2">`  If you really like the look of frames you can achieve the same effect with scrolling divs and you would only need one page.  I recommend you add a css tag to this question