# Classic ASP web page not working in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, asp-classic, render

I have a classic asp application with Frameset as parent tag and Frame (child tag). The Web page is mainly for login purposes (simple web page). It works fine in IE but doesn't render anything in Chrome or Firefox.

Are frames and Frameset supported in Chrome/Firefox??

Comment: I hate framesets - they're a curse on programmers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are frames deprecated in html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263509/why-are-frames-deprecated-in-html)

Comment: How are we meant to debug your code without any example of your code?

Comment: Short answer is: Yes frames are still supported in Chrome and FireFox, see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/ in Chrome and FireFox. Please provide an example demonstrating the problem. Also check you are **not** using the HTML5 doctype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frames are deprecated in general. You should rewrite your solution and use IFRAME, if you have to.

However, even better solution would be not to use frames at all and create some pop-up div (or rather section) and make Ajax call to server side.

Comment: **+1** for *if you have to* in the first para, **-1** for *create some pop-up div* in the second. Just design the page properly and you don't need all the gimmicky junk.

Comment: :D  agree, but I guess majority loves thos gimmickes, that's why I suggested it. Furthermore, if you build app in classic ASP, one might as well use some front-end tricks to make it look more up-to-date...

Comment: I'd vote that comment down, to be honest.  You can do as much with the design of a Classic ASP site as you can with a .NET site - after all, .NET still produces HTML at the other end. What makes the site look pretty is how well it's designed. You can pretty both sites up with jQuery and Ajax if you wish.

Comment: Check out this company's site: [Classic ASP Square](http://www.classicaspsquare.com/).

Comment: I would have loved to know that site back 8 years ago when I was the single one defending classic ASP over ASP.NET in some issues in asp.net forums :)

Comment: Nice comment, @frumbert. Will have to try that (a lot of my work *still* seems to be Classic ASP, and I get fed up of having to sanitise bad coding ... saying that, you should see some of the ASP.NET sites I have to deal with :o| ). Dalibor; me too! They use MVC to drive development - fantastic!

Comment: Frames work fine in all browsers. I do not know of a browser that has dropped support for frames. I think something else is happening but we need to see the code to make a determination. Many people don't LIKE frames, but that does not mean you can't use them.