# Auto/full height on <object> with html file

Tags: html, css, object

I have a problem

How to get full height to content.html, so the entire html file is displayed, no matter how large it is, and not in a small frame?

I have tried "auto" in height but it just gets smaller

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

#left {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: #000000;
  left: -1px;
}

#top {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Home - Jens Peter Halkjær Jensen</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="top"><object width="100%" height="50" data="menus/top.html"></object></div>
  <div id="left"><object width="210" height="100%" data="menus/left.html"></object></div>
  <div id="content"><object width="100%" height="100%" data="content.html"></object></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why do you use the `object` element in order to display html file? You should use `iframe`

Comment: From your sample code it seems that you are trying to reinvent pages with frames, which are not used anymore for [several reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4263509/49934). You shouldn't do that, nowadays there are a lot of better ways of making web pages. If you want to have several "page blocks" that you can reuse it's a good idea, just glue it together with [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), [Server Side Includes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/676394/49934) or even [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9003363/49934).

Comment: My problem with iframe is that there is a white frame around the frame that I do not want

Comment: <iframe src="menus/left.html" width="210" height="100%"></iframe>